# Read a directed graph in R

Tags: r, graph, path, igraph

I have trouble reading/creating a directed graph. I followed the steps I have found [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/snplot.htm).

This is my text file *graph.txt*:

```
1 2
1 3
2 5
3 4
3 5
4 5
5 6
5 10
6 7
7 8
7 9
7 12
8 9
9 10
9 11
9 12
10 11
11 7
11 12
```

Now I read this *graph.txt*:

```
library("igraph")
xlist<-read.graph("graph.txt", format="edgelist")
```

And then I plot it:

```
plot(xlist)
```

But it is not the graph I have read into xlist:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/dubQh.png]

As you can see there is no edge between 1->2, 1->3, 5->10 and so on. How can I read the directed graph correctly?

Having done this, how can I show all shortest paths between two nodes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to work fine for me:

```
 xlist<-read.table("graph.txt")
 xlist <- graph.data.frame(xlist)
 plot(xlist)
```

Note `R` changes nodes and indexes them from zero upwards (not in the most recent `igraph` update as @Sacha Epskamp comments below).
Using:

```
plot(xlist, vertex.label= V(xlist)$name)
```

you will see the names that you want. i.e. edges between 1 and 2.

One way to plot shortest paths is use `get.all.shortest.paths` and then use this to subset your graph and overplot it. See my [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13439030/1317221) for similar example where I plot a spanning tree.

Comment: "Note R changes nodes and indexes them from zero upwards" this has been changed in a recent `igraph` update.

Answer (score 5):

The reason for the error is that edge list files (i.e. format `"edgelist"`) number the vertices from zero. This is the same in all igraph versions, even if recent R igraph packages number the vertices from one.

The reason for this is that is we want R igraph to be consistent with Python igraph and C igraph, as far as file formats go. I.e. a file (in this case an edge list file) written by Python igraph is interpreted the same way by R igraph and Python igraph. The zero-based numbering is a property of the file format.

If you already have an edge list file that starts numbering the vertices with one, that is not the igraph `edgelist` file format, and you need to convert it, by simply subtracting one from each vertex id.

A workaround is to read in the file with `scan()` or `read.table()` (`scan()` is much faster, which might be important if you have large files), and then call `graph()` directly. In this case you don't need to subtract one, because in R igraph vertex ids are numbered from one.