# wrong labels on a directed graph in R

Tags: r, graph

(Hi,

I have yet another question in R and I do not know what I am doing wrong. In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604732/read-a-directed-graph-in-r) I have asked how to read the directed graph which worked well with the answer of user1317221_G.

Now I've deleted the edge 6->7 from the directed graph and read it that way:

```
library(igraph)
graph2 <- read.table("Graph_2.txt")
graph2 <- graph.data.frame(graph2)
```

That's how Graph_2.txt looks like:

```
1 2 
1 3 
2 5 
3 4 
3 5 
4 5 
5 6 
5 10 
7 8 
7 9 
7 12 
8 9 
9 10 
9 11 
9 12
10 7 
10 11
11 7
11 12
```

But the plot shows (again, like in the other thread) a different directed graph:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/zMCxJ.png]

As you can see in the file, there is no edge between 5->9 or from 10->12 as an example. So my question, again, is, how can I read the directed graph correctly? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the vertices labels as you create the graph using `graph.data.frame`, via its `vertices` option:

```
graph2 <- graph.data.frame(graph2, vertices = data.frame(symbols = 1:12,
                                                         label   = 1:12))

plot(graph2, layout = layout.fruchterman.reingold)
```

[image: directed graph with proper labels]